# Is drupal provided Subscription Management functionality for user?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

> I am new in drupal and i have no idea about Subscription Management
>   of users.

Our client want a functionality like.

1) Subscription form for the Non-subscribe USER

**Non-subscribe** :-

> Access Site, Don't have access to open link which is shared by
>   subscribe user

**Subscribe User**:-

> Take subscription,Mention reson to unscribe subscription plan,
>   Informed via SMS/Mail once the content is close to the end of its
>   access time.

(2) Subscription Management

**Manage Subscription Request through Form**:

1. Possibility to choose monthly payment or one-time payment for one year with a discount of 10%
2. Creation of an internal file with Credit Cards EOV (End Of Validity) and CB for reminders
3. add extra fields.
4. possibility to pay via Paypal or similar.  Alert sent directly to the subscriber a month before on his e-mail address

i tried two module **newsletter** and second is **subscriptions**

Links of module

[newsletter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/newsletter)
[subscriptions Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions)

but that can not provided functionality that i mentioned above, So anyone  know about it how Manage Subscription Request through Form or Subscription form for the Non-subscribe USER.

Does anyone know about manage subscription request is done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an out-of-the box solution/module to do what you're asking, but it should be relitivaly straight froward with a combination of modules.

You can control access using core `role`s. Define the roles and access you want them to have.

You could assign and remove roles using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Adding custom fields to nodes is straight forward and can be achived in the UI by going to Structure > Content Types > {Your content type} > manage fields.

As for ecom, and a turnkey solution, you could look at [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license), or [Commerce subscription products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_sp)